# Playing video from a container

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avkit

I am trying to play a video from a `URL`. I am passing the video URL but the problem I have now is that I passed the video container into a `UIView` because I just want it to play in the container. now the video does not play.

```
 func setup() {
    playervc.view.frame = vidContainer.bounds
    self.addChild(playervc)
    vidContainer.addSubview(playervc.view)
    playervc.didMove(toParent: self)
    playervc.player?.play()
  }


extension ProfileVC: AVPlayerViewControllerDelegate {
    private func videoPlayer(url: String) {
        let videoURL = URL(string: url)
        player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL!)
        playervc = AVPlayerViewController()
        playervc.delegate = self
        playervc.player = player
    }
}
```

Comment: If it works outside of that view container, id assume it something to do with the layout not your code. Id double check there isn't something blocking the video in the ViewController

Comment: I can't understood these lines.  `self.addChild(playervc)
    vidContainer.addSubview(playervc.view)
    playervc.didMove(toParent: self)`. What is `self.addChild(playervc)` where you adding your **playervc** etc...

Answer (score 0):

> playervc.videoPlayer(url: "Some Video URL")

call this function in setup()

```
func setup(){

   //This should be call in this function
   playervc.videoPlayer(url: "Some Video URL") 

   playervc.view.frame = vidContainer.bounds
   self.addChild(playervc)
   vidContainer.addSubview(playervc.view)
   playervc.didMove(toParent: self)
   playervc.player?.play()

}
```